# WebApi treating integers values in JSON as true

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, swagger-ui

I have a .net core WebApi and swagger to test the API. Now my problem is when I specify numbers for a boolean field in my JSON data for a POST request, in my controller method it is treating as True, which I don't want

Here is my model:

```cs
{
    public bool Field1 { get; set; }
    public bool Field2 { get; set; }
}
```

```
{
    field1: 2
    field2: true
}
```

And this is how I see the values in the controller

```
{
    field1: true
    field2: true
}
```

Here I don't want integer 2 for field1 to be treated as true and instead, the request should fail

Any recommendations or suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the request to fail, you will have create a custom `set` method for the `boolean` properties and throw an exception as per the failure observed. Something like below:

```
private bool _field1;
public bool Field1
{ 
    get
    { 
        return _field1; 
    }
    set
    {
        if(value.GetType() == typeof(bool))
        {
            _field1 = value;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Value "+value+" is not of valid type.");   // type of exception can be as per the failure observed
        }
    }
}
```

Now, within the action method, you should check for `ModelState` errors. For that you can do:

```
public IHttpActionResult SomeAction([FromBody] RequestModel request)
{
    if(!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        foreach (var modelState in ModelState.Values)
        {
            foreach (var error in modelState.Errors)
            {
              //collate the errors and send appropriate response back
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
         // do your usual logic
    }
}
```

You will be getting the exception in a format like:

> Exception = {System.ArgumentException: Value 1 is not of
>   valid type .......

Hope this helps.